# R Streamline For Loop with Nested IfElse

Tags: r

I'm trying to think of a way to run this script in something other than a for loop. I've tried a by function, but that didn't work for me. Ideally it would be able to be done within base R.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What this code does is...
1. Creates df planTable
2. planTable starts with the first three rows of the table below.
3. Iterates from stage = 1 to numOfStages = 20
4. Jumps into the for loop with stage = 1 and follows the if(stage==1) statement
5. jumps out of that ifelse and follows the code throughout
6. After it has completed the for loop the final result is the table you see below.

```
     TIME STAGE WELL_NM
1  0.0000     0 2. PLAN
2  0.7000     0 2. PLAN
3  0.7000     1 2. PLAN

MIRU <- 0.7
numofStages <- 20
fG <- 4
GR <- .000034
nptPer <- .0030
STIM <- .0001


TIME <- c(0, MIRU, MIRU)
STAGE <- c(0, 0, 1)
WELL_NM <- c("2. PLAN", "2. PLAN", "2. PLAN")

planTable <- data.frame(TIME, STAGE, WELL_NM)

Row <- 4

for (stage in 1:numOfStages)
{
  if (stage == 1) {
    planTable[Row, 1] <- planTable[Row - 1, 1] + nptPer
    planTable[Row, 2] <- stage
    planTable[Row, 3] <- "2. PLAN"
    Row=Row + 1
  } else {
    if (stage == 2) {
      perf <-(KOP / vtRIH) 
    } 
      else {
        perf <-KOP * (1 / vtRIH + 1 / vtPOOH)
      }
      planTable[Row, 1] =  planTable[Row - 1, 1] + .5* nptPer
      planTable[Row, 2] = stage
      planTable[Row, 3] = "2. PLAN"
      Row=Row + 1
      if(stage %% fG==0){
        mantc<-GR
      }
      else{
        mantc<-0
      }
    planTable[Row, 1] =  planTable[Row - 1, 1] + STIM
    planTable[Row, 2] = stage
    planTable[Row, 3] = "2. PLAN"
    Row=Row + 1
  }

}
```

The output would be a dataframe...

```
    TIME STAGE WELL_NM
1  0.000     0 2. PLAN
2  0.026     0 2. PLAN
3  0.026     1 2. PLAN
4  0.028     1 2. PLAN
5  0.030     2 2. PLAN
6  0.031     2 2. PLAN
7  0.033     3 2. PLAN
8  0.034     3 2. PLAN
9  0.036     4 2. PLAN
10 0.037     4 2. PLAN
11 0.039     5 2. PLAN
12 0.040     5 2. PLAN
13 0.041     6 2. PLAN
14 0.043     6 2. PLAN
15 0.044     7 2. PLAN
16 0.046     7 2. PLAN
17 0.047     8 2. PLAN
18 0.049     8 2. PLAN
19 0.050     9 2. PLAN
20 0.052     9 2. PLAN
21 0.053    10 2. PLAN
22 0.054    10 2. PLAN
23 0.056    11 2. PLAN
24 0.057    11 2. PLAN
25 0.059    12 2. PLAN
26 0.060    12 2. PLAN
27 0.062    13 2. PLAN
28 0.063    13 2. PLAN
29 0.064    14 2. PLAN
30 0.066    14 2. PLAN
31 0.067    15 2. PLAN
32 0.069    15 2. PLAN
33 0.070    16 2. PLAN
34 0.072    16 2. PLAN
35 0.073    17 2. PLAN
36 0.075    17 2. PLAN
37 0.076    18 2. PLAN
38 0.077    18 2. PLAN
39 0.079    19 2. PLAN
40 0.080    19 2. PLAN
41 0.082    20 2. PLAN
42 0.083    20 2. PLAN
43 0.085    21 2. PLAN
44 0.086    21 2. PLAN
45 0.087    22 2. PLAN
46 0.089    22 2. PLAN
47 0.090    23 2. PLAN
48 0.092    23 2. PLAN
```

Comment: I'll update my question and script.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe in words what your code does?

Comment: Just updated my question.  Let me know if that gives enough detail.